# How to restrict end datetime based on dropdown selection in bootstrap date time picker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

Hi am trying to restrict end date time selection based on the drop down selection, say i have drop down ,Start date and End date. if i select option 1 from drop down the time difference should be in end date time picker from start date is half an hour , if i option 2 from date the time difference should be in end date time picker from start date is three hour

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0p813h0e/

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Notice Type</label>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
    <select name="noticeType" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
    </select>
    </div>                                          
    </div>

        <div class="input-append date form_datetime" data-date="2013-02-21T15:25:00Z">
            <input size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
<div class="input-append date form_datetime" data-date="2013-02-21T15:25:00Z">
            <input size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
```

```js
 $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
        format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true,
        startDate: "2013-02-14 10:00",
        minuteStep: 10
    });
```